# Running a cumulative Union in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get a list, a total, and a cumulative total in the same column.  So far I have the list and the total for that date range, but moving forward I would like to get a cumulative total.  Here is the code i'm using, please note temp_2 and temp_3 yield the same results;

```
Select School,Principal, NumberOfObs    
From temp_2     
Union     
Select '','TOTAL',Sum(NumberOfObs)     
From temp_3;
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts:  Why union?  Look at [group by modifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) `with rollup` for total and for the running total look at using user variables like in [this prior stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032360/running-sums-for-multiple-categories-in-mysql)

Comment: Plus this seems to require pivoting as well

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Calculate a running total in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/664700/3664960)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate of that, because i'm wanting the cumulative total at the bottom of the column, not in an extra column.  I'm still working my way through it.