# MySQL subtract if found, show null or zero if not

Tags: mysql

I need to match values from the same table and show the subtraction of them. However, some values might not match (because they do not exist) and in that case I should show null or zero.

```
Table purchase_items
---------------------
ID | purchase_id | item_id | quantity
1    103           1         10
2    103           2         5 
3    103           3         20
4    104           1         5
5    104           2         5
```

The desired output is:

```
item_id | Original quantity | New quantity | Total
1         10                  5              5
2         5                   5              0
3         20                  null/0         20
```

Currently I'm not able to present the last row. With the query below I can only reproduce:

```
item_id | Original quantity | New quantity | Total
1         10                  5              5
2         5                   5              0

SELECT 
    original.quantity AS `Original quantity`,
    new.quantity AS `New quantity`,
    (original.quantity - new.quantity) AS total
FROM
    purchase_items AS original,
    purchase_items AS new
WHERE
    original.purchase_id = 103 AND new.purchase_id = 104 AND original.item_id = new.item_id
```

And I do realize the problem is within `original.item_id = new.item_id` but how can I overcome this problem?

---

**EDIT:**  It seems my post is confusing. I'll try to explain it in a better way.

I'm trying to understand the items sold in the previous document and compare to the items sold in the current document.

My table is the following:

```
Table purchase_items
---------------------
ID | purchase_id | item_id | quantity
1    103           1         10
2    103           2         5 
3    103           3         20
4    104           1         5
5    104           2         5
```

From this values you can understand the following situations from **item 1** (**and same applies to item 2**):

1. The item 1 sold 10 units in the purchase document 103
2. The item 1 sold 5 units in the purchase document 104
3. The item 1 has a total of 5 units remaining (10-5 = 5)

So, the output must be:

```
item_id | Original quantity | New quantity
1         10                  5          
2         5                   5
```

Now, if you look at the table there's an **item 3**, **which was sold in the purchase document 103 but not in the purchase document 104**! With that said, the output should be

```
item_id | Original quantity | New quantity
1         10                  5          
2         5                   5
3         20                  0/null
```

Forget about the subtraction, because I can do it in PHP if necessary.

Take a look at this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d250f5/1)**.

Comment: learn about `outer join`

Comment: @Jens ...that isn't much help, like the post you deleted wasn't.

Comment: With your sample data and query, seems to not get the result you've post.

Comment: The only thing wrong in my code was the numbers of `purchase_id` and I've correct them now.

Comment: I think you want to calculate a running sum? Look e.g. at [Running Sums for Multiple Categories in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032360/running-sums-for-multiple-categories-in-mysql). Since your first row is special (all others have an implied "-"-sign (you might want to think about if you want to add it for real!), you can use `if(@item = item_id,@sum-Quantity,Quantity)` in the second approach of the first answer. In your query, the very hard thing is that you don't have an order. Try adding some more rows for the same item_id and see for yourself!

Comment: @Solarflare please see my edit.

Comment: In that case, you can use P.Salmons solution with your values in the `on`-clause: `on p1.purchase_id = 103 and p2.purchase_id = 104 and p1.item_id = p2.item_id`. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, never mind. I gave another try on his code with some changes and worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE sandbox;
/*
create Table purchase_items
(ID int, purchase_id int, item_id int, quantity int);
insert into purchase_items
values
(1,    1,             1,         10),
(2,    1,             2,         5 ),
(3,    1,             3,         20),
(4,    2,             1,         5),
(5,    2,             2,         5)
;
item_id | Original quantity | New quantity | Total
1         10                  5              5
2         5                   5              0
3         20                  null/0         20 

*/

    select  p1.id,p1.quantity as old_quantity,p2.quantity as new_quantity,
            case 
            when    p2.quantity is null then p1.quantity
            else    p1.quantity - p2.quantity
            end     as total
    from    purchase_items p1
    left outer join purchase_items p2 on p2.purchase_id = p1.purchase_id + 1 and p2.item_id = p1.item_id
    where   p1.purchase_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using left join helps, as i wrote in y comment. This query gives yu the correct result:

```
SELECT original.item_id,
    original.quantity AS `Original quantity`,
    new.quantity AS `New quantity`,
    (original.quantity - new.quantity) AS total
FROM
    purchase_items AS original left join
    purchase_items AS new on original.item_id = new.item_id
 and
    original.purchase_id = 103 AND new.purchase_id = 104 
    group by original.item_id
```

As you can see in the [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d250f5/11)